# Does Robot Framework have more to offer than Cucumber?

Tags: test-automation-framework, cucumber

I have some experience with Robot Framework + Selenium and am now learning Cucumber, since I noticed it's one of the most widely used frameworks in test automation. However, from what I've seen so far, Cucumber seems to lacks what makes RF suitable for people with no programming skills: keyword libraries.

With RF I can use a Selenium Library that already has the most common actions implemented: Go To Url, Click Button, Mouse Over, Input Text and so on. In addition, there are many other libraries with other common actions, like string handling, database access, etc. I'm just starting with baby steps in the Cucumber world, but I've not seen anything like that in the framework, meaning that I will have to implement those by writing the Selenium code myself. Is it so, or I'm missing something? Why all the fuss around Cucumber if it doesn't provide things half-way done as RF does?

Comment: I think both of the frameworks can be customized by adding your own keywords, so your question does not really apply

Comment: Well, you can implement your own keywords in Robot Framework, yes. But usually you can manage a good deal of testing without them, since RF presents you with almost 200 already implemented keywords ready to use. That's exactly my question: wouldn't this leave Cucumber at greate disadvantage?

Comment: Not necessarily, from my own experience, the off the shelf keywords do not always give you what you want, you will end up writing your own keywords every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is not designed to provide pre-built libraries like Robot Framework. Instead, it focuses on providing a structure for writing and executing human-readable acceptance tests that can be understood by both technical and non-technical stakeholders. In Cucumber, you write the tests in a language called Gherkin, which is a plain text language that uses keywords like "Given", "When", and "Then" to describe the behavior of the system. The actual implementation of the tests is done in code, typically using a programming language like Java, Ruby, or JavaScript. This code is then executed by Cucumber and the results are reported back to the user.

While it is true that you have to write the code for the tests yourself, this can also be seen as a strength of Cucumber, as it allows for greater flexibility and control over the tests. Additionally, because the tests are written in a plain text language, they can be easily understood and maintained by non-technical stakeholders, which can help to ensure that everyone is on the same page with regards to the expected behavior of the system.

In conclusion, while Cucumber may not provide pre-built libraries like Robot Framework, it still provides a powerful and flexible framework for writing and executing acceptance tests, and its focus on human-readable tests can be a valuable asset in ensuring that everyone is on the same page with regards to the expected behavior of the system.